# time picker returning null value if start and end time both same

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar, bootstrap-4

```
 <input type="text" id="from" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" name="start_activity">

<input type="text" id="to" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-no-seconds" name="end_activity">

In script for both is :
$('#from').timepicker();
 $('#to').timepicker();
```

i have two time picker in a form but when i am saving start time and end time as same then like start is 4pm and end also 4pm then it returning me the null value in end time when i am getting the value from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Array.filter:

```
...
events: <?= $response ?>.filter(function(x) { return x.status === "1";}),
...
```

If you do it this way (or the way you have it) please ensure that the $response variable always results in an array, even if empty, or you will have headaches.

Comment: i want when status is 1 it work with my code but if status ==2 then it dont show on my events of calendar how can i hide it on status ===2

Comment: RichGoldMD @ richard i wana ask u samthing if i am saving start time and end time as same then like start is 4pm and end also 4pm them it returning me the null value in end time

Comment: I don't know enough about the data source, but what is the problem? If the control can't handle null you could use array.map to process the array and make the end time equal to the start time if the end time is null. You could chain the map call to the result of the array.filter call like ...filter(...).map(function (x) {...}) you will need to write the code that checks and updates the event elements

Comment: There isn't really enough information to help you here. It sounds like it should be a new question with more detail